# CLion linking library not detecting class yet the app works

Tags: c++, clion

I am learning C++ and I am using JetBrains CLion C++ IDE. I am just knocking together a quick test.

I have a library project which has a class Welcome with one method. Below is the Welcome.h header

```
class Welcome
{
public:
    void sayHello(string firstName, string lastName);
};
```

The Welcome.cpp file

```
void Welcome::sayHello(string firstName, string lastName)
{
    cout << "Hello " << firstName << " " << lastName << endl;
}
```

In my test app I have the following in the CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(TestApp)

include_directories(includes C:\\Users\\Chris\\ClionProjects\\MyLib\\includes)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp TestClass.cpp)

add_executable(TestApp ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(TestApp C:\\Users\\Chris\\Desktop\\MyLib.a)
```

In main.cpp I have the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include "TestClass.h"
#include "Welcome.h"

int main() {

    TestClass testClass;
    testClass.helloWorld();

    Welcome welcome;
    welcome.sayHello("First", "Last");
    return 0;
}
```

CLion is happily finding the Welcome.h
CLion successfully compiles and runs the project and in the console it outputs `Hello First Last`

But even though it runs, and CLion successfully runs it, the IDE shows Welcome in red and when hovering the mouse over it is `Can't resolve type 'Welcome'`

How can this happen, am I missing something or this a bug in CLion? I'm assuming its me it seems like quite a simple bug and I've used JetBrains other IDEs such as PHPStorm and Android Studio which are really good.

Comment: "But even though it runs, and CLion successfully runs it, the IDE shows Welcome in red and when hovering the mouse over it is Can't resolve type 'Welcome'

How can this happen" - It can happen because the code in your IDE that tries to help you by checking for simple errors is not actually a real compiler - it doesn't actually compile your code it just does some basic sanity checks and employs some heuristics. That means that your IDE can very often be *wrong*. The only authoritative source on whether your code is syntactically valid and can be compiled is *the compiler*.

Answer (score 2):

With a bit of trial and error I've been able to get it to work, but it doesn't seem to be well documented.

I have modified the following in the CMakeLists.txt file of the test app

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(TestApp)

include_directories(includes C:\\Users\\Chris\\ClionProjects\\MyLib\\includes)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp TestClass.cpp)

add_executable(TestApp ${SOURCE_FILES})
add_library(myLib.a)
set_target_properties(myLib.a PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
target_link_libraries(TestApp C:\\Users\\Chris\\Desktop\\myLib.a)
```

Notice the following two lines added

```
add_library(myLib.a)
set_target_properties(myLib.a PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets give you a hint on that, most of the errors than Clion show is from Cmake (or GDB on compilation). Whenever you stuck in something, first check Cmake documentations, you probably get to find the answer in Cmakelists.txt modification.

Answer (score 0):

I have a mixed C/C++ application. Most (perhaps all) of the C++ specific language constructs were not recognized and many definitions not recognized from within `.cpp` files.

My `CMakeLists.txt` began with

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(hvr-hvr LANGUAGES C)

message( STATUS "CMAKE_C_COMPILER: " ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER} )
...
```

After the following modification to the `project` line, all is well:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(hvr-hvr LANGUAGES C CXX)

message( STATUS "CMAKE_C_COMPILER: " ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER} )
...
```

(Note the addition of `CXX` to the list of `LANGUAGES`.